# Why recursion is slower than iteration in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, iteration

I try to a question very similar to the Fibonacci number.

when I try to write code in recursion style

```
import time
def stepPerms(n):
  if n==1:
    return 1
  elif n==2:
    return 2
  elif n == 3:
    return 4
  else:
    return stepPerms(n-1)+stepPerms(n-2)+stepPerms(n-3)
t0= time.time()
print(stepPerms(36)%(10**10+7))
t1= time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

I got execution time

```
175.47555208206177
```

When re-written same code using an iterative style

```
import time
def stepPerms(n):
    l=[0]*n
    if n==1:
        return 1
    elif n==2:
        return 2
    elif n == 3:
        return 4
    else:
        l[0]=1
        l[1]=2
        l[2]=4
        for i in range(3,n):
            l[i]=l[i-1]+l[i-2]+l[i-3]
        return l[n-1]
t0= time.time()
print(stepPerms(36)%(10**10+7))
t1= time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

I got execution time

```
0.0010170936584472656
```

**Can you tell why execution time is coming from different recursion and iteration style code?**

Comment: The recursion is branching. In the iteration you just sum the values you already assigned. In the recursion scenarios you are computing the three values at each invocation. So in other words, stepPerms(n-1) is not returning a saved value, but will be computing it.

Comment: You are mistaking time complexity with execution time. It is not the same.

Comment: @Netwave Thank you for point out, ActuallyI am askingabout execution time only .

Answer (score 0):

The first example is simply doing repeated work. Consider how many times stepPerms(1) is called, in total.